# Count number of words in a file using dictionary comprehension - python

Tags: python

In the following code using dictionary comprehension am trying to count the total number of words with duplicates but this results in `{'count': 1, 'words.As': 1, 'said': 1, 'file.\n': 1, 'this': 1, 'text': 1, 'is': 1, 'of': 1, 'some': 1, ',i': 1, 'to': 1, 'only': 1, 'Hi': 1, 'a': 1, 'file': 1, 'recognize': 1, 'test': 1, 'the': 1, 'repeat': 1, 'before': 1}`

I do not see `is` twice or any of them for the matter what am i doing wrong here?

test_readme.txt

`Hi this is some text to recognize the count of words.As said before this is only a test file ,i repeat test file.`

```
with open('test_readme.txt') as f:
   di = { w : di[w]+1 if w in di else 1  for l in f for w in l.split(' ')}
print di
```

Comment: I see `is` twice: `is some text to recognize the count of words.As said before this is`

Comment: I get a `TypeError: expected a character buffer object` exception from your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access `di` while it is being populated.

Instead, simply use a `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()
with open('test_readme.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        counter += Counter(line.split())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use dictionary comprehension. Because `di` doesn't change during it's creation and your code will raise a `NameError` if you didn't defined the dictionary already.

```
>>> s = """Hi this is some text to recognize the count of words.
... As said before this is only a test file ,i repeat test file."""
>>> 
>>> di = { w : di[w]+1 if w in di else 1 for l in s.split('\n') for w in l.split(' ')}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
NameError: global name 'di' is not defined
```

You can use a `defaultdict()` or `Counter()` from `collections` module:

```
from collections import defaultdict

di = defaultdict(int)
with open('test_readme.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
       for w in line.strip().split():
           di[w]+=1
```

Demo :

```
>>> for line in s.split('\n'):
...    for w in line.strip().split():
...            di[w]+=1
... 
>>> di
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'count': 1, 'a': 1, 'said': 1, 'words.': 1, 'this': 2, 'text': 1, 'is': 2, 'of': 1, 'some': 1, 'only': 1, ',i': 1, 'to': 1, 'As': 1, 'Hi': 1, 'file': 1, 'recognize': 1, 'test': 2, 'the': 1, 'file.': 1, 'repeat': 1, 'before': 1})
>>>
```

Comment: In python cant we refer to the current object for your di example ?

Comment: No you cant, 99% of the python is about runtime. It will define the objects in runtime, and until the end of your operations python doesn't create the `di`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use counter but on the whole string:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('readme.txt') as f:
   s = Counter(f.read().replace('\n', '').split(' '))

#Out[8]: Counter({'this': 2, 'is': 2, 'test': 2, 'count': 1, 'words.As': 1, 'said': 1, 'text': 1, 'of': 1, 'some': 1, ',i': 1, 'to': 1, 'only': 1, 'Hi': 1, 'a': 1, 'file': 1, '
#recognize': 1, 'the': 1, 'file.': 1, 'repeat': 1, 'before': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

A very readable solution would be

```
Thedict = {}
fo = open('sample.txt')
for line in fo:
    for word in line.split(' '):
        word = word.strip('.').strip()
        if(word in Thedict):
            Thedict[word] = Thedict[word] + 1
        else:
            Thedict[word] = 0

print(Thedict)
```

considering the sample holds the text

Answer (score 1):

Yet another `Counter` solution, runs the file through in a single call to `Counter` iteratively using a nested generator expression:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('test_readme.txt') as f:
    counts = Counter(word for line in f for word in line.strip().split())
```

And as pointed out already, you can't access a variable in the expression that produces the result to assign, or in other words the intermediate results of an expression. The expression is evaluated first and the store performed on the result. Since dictionary comprehension is a single expression, it is evaluated and the result stored.