# Python dictionary comprehensions

Tags: python

I have a string consisting of space separated nos : `5 4 4 2 2 8`.

I want to construct a dictionary out of this which would have the no of times each no appear in the above string .

I first try to construct a list out of the above input line by the below code :

```
nos = input().split(" ")
print (nos)
```

Now i want to iterate through the above list using dict comprehension to create the dictionary .

How can i do the same , can someone please help?

Comment: You can't, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785412/count-number-of-words-in-a-file-using-dictionary-comprehension-python, which is similar. Use a `Counter`.

Comment: plz post what is the output you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

n = "5 4 4 2 2 8"
n = n.split(" ")

occurrences = Counter(n)
```

If you don't want to import anything you can use `count`:

```
n = "5 4 4 2 2 8"
n = n.split(" ")

unique = set(n)

occurences = {i:n.count(i) for i in unique}
```

Output:

```
{'4': 2, '2': 2, '5': 1, '8': 1}
```

Answer (score 3):

You asked for a dict comp so that's what I'll show here, but I also agree that this is a place to use a Counter or derivative:

```
nos = input().split()
my_dict = {k: nos.count(k) for k in set(nos)}
```

It works by first finding the unique elements (by creating a `set`) then using the list `count()` method for every unique element of the input list.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter
Counter('5 4 4 2 2 8'.split(' '))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter);

```
>>> import collections
>>> input_str = '5 4 4 2 2 8'
>>> dict(collections.Counter(input_str.split(" ")))
{'4': 2, '2': 2, '8': 1, '5': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str1 = '5 4 4 2 2 8'
```

function used to create a dictionary :

```
def func_dict(i, dict):
  dict[i] = dict.get(i, 0) + 1
  return dict

d = dict()
( [ func_dict(i, d) for i in str1.split() ] )
print "d :", d
```